# How to customize Tapku calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calendar, tapku

Finally decided to use calendar lib for my training calender application:

I'm trying to customize Tapku calendar...

Just curious to know, How can I add table view and update its cell on the same page(below the calendar)?

Once user selects any perticular date, the event of the perticular date will be shown in the table cell.

Note: I'm using "DidSelectDate" method to show the message.

The problem is, if I'm adding a table view below the calender its not visible.How can i Do this?
Here How I'm doing:
Checking if any date is deleted:

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate %@",d);
//[self papulateTable];
//[table reloadData];
[self performSelector:@selector(papulateTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
//flagtoCheckSelectedCalendarDate = 1;
//[table reloadData];
```

}

populating the table with my custom method by calling reload data:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)papulateTable
{
listOfTrainings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"Objective - C"];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"C#.Net"];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"ASP.Net"];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"JAVA"];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"Memory management"];
[listOfTrainings addObject:@"Multi Threading app"];

NSString *cellValue = [listOfTrainings objectAtIndex:tempIndexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
[table reloadData];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: if you have (faulty) code you should show what you got so far.

Comment: Ok.Now its working...I'm calling [Self ViewDidLoad] after checking condition.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a lot of important methods.

some methods you would like:

```
//Get Visible Cells.
NSArray *cells = [tableview visibleCells];

//Get the index path row of a cell.
NSIndexPath * cellRow = [tableview indexPathForCell:cellPointer];

//Return all visible index row.
NSArray *indexVisibleRows = [tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows];

//Reload Data
[tableview reloadData];
```

Also, you have some delegates, that makes easy control a tableview:

-ScrollView delegates.

-TableView delegates.

take a look with the apple documentation, there are everything you need, just make an strategy
by using the exists methods in tableview.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html